# PySpice: Simulate circuit with capacitor with defined initial condition

Tags: python, initialization, simulation, circuit, pyspice

with PySpice I'm trying to simulate the discharging behavior of a capacitor with a defined initial condition in a circuit. This is a simplified example:

```
import PySpice.Logging.Logging as Logging
logger = Logging.setup_logging()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PySpice.Spice.Netlist import Circuit
from PySpice.Unit import *

V1 = 10
circuit.V("1","node2", circuit.gnd, V1)
circuit.R("1", "node1", "node2", 3.5)
circuit.C("1", "node1", circuit.gnd, 100, initial_condition = 20)

simulator = circuit.simulator(temperature=25, nominal_temperature=25)

analysis = simulator.transient(step_time=1@u_s, end_time = 10000@u_s)
```

After running the simulation, I would expect an exponential discharge of the capacitor: The voltage at "node1" should start at "initial_condition" and end at voltage of "node2".
But the voltage at "node1" stays at V1 for the complete simulation. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First of all your code is not runnable: You have to define a Circuit object.

There seems to be a discussion relating to this at [issue](https://github.com/PySpice-org/PySpice/issues/49)

## Reproducing Problem

#### Modified Code Block:

```
## imports

V1 = 10
R1 = 3.5
C1 = 100
C1_ic = 20

circuit = Circuit("circuit")

circuit.V("1","node2", circuit.gnd, V1)
circuit.R("1", "node1", "node2", R1)
circuit.C("1", "node1", circuit.gnd, C1, initial_condition=C1_ic)

simulator = circuit.simulator(temperature=25, nominal_temperature=25)
analysis = simulator.transient(step_time=u_ms(1), end_time=u_ms(1000))

print(simulator)
```

#### Output Netlist:

```
.title circuit
V1 node2 0 10
R1 node1 node2 3.5
C1 node1 0 100 ic=20
.options TEMP = 25C
.options TNOM = 25C
.end
```

This netlist produces the desired output with LTSpice but seems to not work on PySpice for some reason.

## Solution

#### Modified Code Block:

```
## imports


V1 = 10
R1 = 3.5
C1 = 100
C1_ic = 20

circuit = Circuit("circuit")

circuit.V("1","node2", circuit.gnd, V1)
circuit.R("1", "node1", "node2", R1)
circuit.C("1", "node1", circuit.gnd, C1)

simulator = circuit.simulator(temperature=25, nominal_temperature=25)
## initial condition defined with simulator
simulator.initial_condition(node1=C1_ic)
analysis = simulator.transient(step_time=u_ms(1), end_time=u_ms(1000))

print(simulator)
```

#### Output Netlist:

```
.title circuit
V1 node2 0 10
R1 node1 node2 3.5
C1 node1 0 100
.options TEMP = 25C
.options TNOM = 25C
.ic V(node1)=20
.end
```

This way of defining initial conditions is valid and produces correct results on both LTSpice and PySpice Simulation.

## Electrical Engineering Extra

You can plot the result of analysis in python by adding the following lines:

```
plt.plot(analysis.time, analysis["node1"], label="node1")
plt.plot(analysis.time, analysis["node2"], label="node2")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

You'll see that "node1" voltage won't deviate from 20 much. This is due to your circuit parameters (resistance and capacitance). Read about [Time Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_constant), Your time constant is too much compared to your simulation time (100C * 3.5R = 35s >> 10s)